# How to hide unneccessary subfolders in website address in firebase

Tags: html, firebase, url, firebase-hosting

I want to reduce the length of the URLs of my webpages in firebase. The html files are inside of an html folder which is inside the public folder. The URL for the index page right now is: **www.lstein-28b62.web.app/htmlfolder/index.html**
Would it be possible to change this to **www.lstein-28b62.web.app/index.html** without taking the index.html file out of the htmlfolder subfolder? 
I basically just want to hide the /htmlfolder/ subfolder. It should be similar to the js function window.history.pushState(), although this creates problems if the page is refreshed.

Comment: use .htaccess rewrite rules https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

Comment: .htaccess can not be used with firebase

Comment: And symlink? In *nix system you can make link to folder and use like a real path

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Change the [folder you deploy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#public) to `public/html`, so that only the contents of the HTML folder are deployed.

   ```
   "hosting": {
     "public": "public"

     // ...
   }
   ```
2. Use a [rewrite rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) to serve the contents from the root.

   ```
   "hosting": {
     // ...

     // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
     "rewrites": [ {
       "source": "/html/index.html",
       "destination": "/index.html"
     } ]
   }
   ```

I'd highly recommend the first approach, as the latter requires much more maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortuantely, this is not quite what I am looking for. The first approach does not work for me, because I have multiple folders in my public folder which should all be deployed. The second approach is creating problems with the all resources that I stored in the subfolder (e.g. js, css, images). It would be great if could stay on the actual page and the url would just be displayed differently